# Ruby on Rails namespace for models or only controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When creating an admin that manages products, should I only create a Admin namespace for the products controller, or also for the model?

When I also have a namespace for the model I *can not* use the following code for the new action form:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @product] do |f| %>
```

I'll have to use

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
```

and in the controller

```
def new
  @product = Admin::Product.new
end
```

What is the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this would be

routes.rb

```
 namespace :admin do
   resources :products
 end
```

controller admin/products_controller.rb

```
class Admin::ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end
end
```

I don't think you should namespace your model for admin

Comment: Is there an easy way to get the model out of a namespace or should I destroy it and create it again.

Comment: can you show me how have u made ur namespaced model ? you can update you question with that

Comment: I destroyed it and created a new model that is not in the admin namespace. Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I guess `Product` used in `admin` namespace is the same as `Product` used everywhere else. So the answer is, you should not namespace your model in this case.